# Python - how to groupby all rows to one, keeping all columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need some help over here!

I would like to group all rows from dataframe to only one using average for each column, since I have several columns, example:

```
column_1 column_2 column_3 column_4...
  13%       11%      10%      10%
  10%       9%       9%       6%
  14%       10%      9%       NaN
```

Expected dataframe output:

```
    column_1 column_2 column_3 column_4...
       12%      10%      9%       8%
```

The result: (13+10+14)/3 = 12%...

I currently have a lot of work to get the result that I want, export the first dataframe to CSV, open it in Excel and calculate the average.

Comment: is your column_1 a string `13%`?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(df.replace('%','',regex=True).astype(float)  # remove % and convert to number
   .mean().astype(int)                        # compute average and round
   .astype(str).add('%')                      # convert to string and add %
   .to_frame().T                              # change to dataframe
)
```

Output:

```
  column_1 column_2 column_3 column_4
0      12%      10%       9%       8%
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values are already numerical, you can use the `df.apply` method together with a function that calculates what you want:

```
import numpy as np

df.apply(np.mean, axis=0)
```

Comment: thank you for your comment! I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can do a df.groupby.agg() like this.

```
aggs_dict = {col:'mean' for col in df.columns}
print (df.groupby(lambda x: True).agg(aggs_dict))
```